# Does finding a skull do anything?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

In *Legend of Grimrock*, there are several hidden locations. You can find various items in these secret rooms (weapons, armor, etc.).

The one that's piqued my interest the most, however, is the Skull.

[image]

Normally, I'd think nothing of this. Just a skull in a pile of bones. Seems to be fairly common in dungeons like these. The confusing part is: **They get their own section in the Statistics page.**

**Do these skulls do anything for me?** (i.e. will collecting ALL the skulls get me a super-secret ending and/or weapon?)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On Steam you can get an achievement for finding 5 of them.

Besides that, there is a trait for the Minotaurs, called Head Hunter. It gives you +3 Attack for every skull carried in the inventory.

Answer (score 9):

Skulls give boosts to Minotaurs who have the Head Hunter trait.

Answer (score 3):

you need one for a puzzle on level 9 as well

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, skulls give attack bonuses to Minotaur who have the Head Hunter trait. But there is a big caveat here, which I have only just learned on level 10 out of 13. :(

You only get the bonus to attack if you are carrying the skulls in your Minotaur's inventory, NOT if it is in a sack or chest! Gaaaaah!